# Command line output not redirecting to file.

Tags: windows, command-line

Very simple:

Open a console, and type

`mkdir abc > output.txt`

it creates a file called output.txt which is empty.

now repeat

`mkdir abc > output.txt`

This displays on the command window:

`A subdirectory or file abc already exists`

but does not output this to the txt.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're redirecting standard output to your file; errors are typically reported on standard error, which is a different output stream. To redirect standard error, you can do this:

```
mkdir abc 2> output.txt
```

Or, if you want to combine both streams and direct them together:

```
mkdir abc 2>&1 >output.txt
```

More details [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 1):

This will silently create a folder, if it exists or not.

```
mkdir abc 2>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the output of mkdir for the second call goes to stderr instead of stdout.